# Pivoting Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have the following tables:

```
Items
______
Item_ID
Item_Name
...


Properties
___________
Item_ID
Property_ID
Property_Value_ID

PropertyTypes
_______________
Property_Type_ID
Property_Type_Name


PropertyValues
_______________
Property_Type_ID
Value_ID
Value_Name
```

and a query

```
SELECT pt.PROPERTY_TYPE_NAME, pv.VALUE_NAME
FROM Property_Types pt, PropertyValues pv, Properties p
WHERE pt.PROPERTY_TYPE_ID = pv.PROPERTY_TYPE_ID
AND pv.VALUE_ID = p.PROPERTY_VALUE_ID
AND p.ITEM_ID = 1;
```

That gives me 3 rows for each of the three properties but what I want is one row where PROPERTY_TYPE_NAME is a column name and PROPERTY_VALUE as a column value

what I have is

```
 Column1|Column2 |Column3| Column4|Column5| Column6
 Type1  | Value1 | Type2 | Value2 | Type3 | Value3
```

what I need is

```
Type1  | Type2 | Type3
Value1 | Value2| Value3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(CASE WHEN pt.PROPERTY_TYPE_NAME = 'Type1' THEN pv.VALUE_NAME END) type1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pt.PROPERTY_TYPE_NAME = 'Type2' THEN pv.VALUE_NAME END) type2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pt.PROPERTY_TYPE_NAME = 'Type3' THEN pv.VALUE_NAME END) type3
FROM 
    Property_Types pt
    INNER JOIN PropertyValues pv ON pt.PROPERTY_TYPE_ID = pv.PROPERTY_TYPE_ID
    INNER JOIN Properties p ON pv.VALUE_ID = p.PROPERTY_VALUE_ID
WHERE p.ITEM_ID = 1;
```

Side note: *always* use explicit, standard joins (with the `JOIN ... ON ...` syntax) rather than old-school, implicit joins (with commas in the `FROM` clause), whose syntax has fallen out of favor since ANSI SQL 92. I modified your query accordingly.

Note that you can sligthly modify the query so it can handle more than one `ITEM_ID` at a time:

```
SELECT 
    p.ITEM_ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pt.PROPERTY_TYPE_NAME = 'Type1' THEN pv.VALUE_NAME END) type1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pt.PROPERTY_TYPE_NAME = 'Type2' THEN pv.VALUE_NAME END) type2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pt.PROPERTY_TYPE_NAME = 'Type3' THEN pv.VALUE_NAME END) type3
FROM 
    Property_Types pt
    INNER JOIN PropertyValues pv ON pt.PROPERTY_TYPE_ID = pv.PROPERTY_TYPE_ID
    INNER JOIN Properties p ON pv.VALUE_ID = p.PROPERTY_VALUE_ID
GROUP BY p.ITEM_ID;
```

Comment: any way I can do that without having to specify all the values of a property_type_name? I might not know these ahead of time

Comment: @CodingDuchess: in standard SQL, this is not possible. A SQL query must return a *fixed* list of columns. For what you ask for, you would need to use *dynamic* SQL (generate a query string on the fly, then execute it), which is a different beast.

Comment: Thanks for your help!